# error: qtquick2applicationviewer.h: No such file or directory

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2

My `.pro` file:

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = qmllistproperties
INCLUDEPATH += .
CONFIG += qt plugin
QT += qml quick

# Input
HEADERS += aa.h DummyClass.h
SOURCES += aa.cpp DummyClass.cpp
```

Have included it in .cpp like: `#include "qtquick2applicationviewer.h"`

What am I missing?

Comment: Is `qtquick2applicationviewer.h` in the same directory with your .cpp file that includes it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have these two lines in your `.pro` file:

```
include(qtquick2applicationviewer/qtquick2applicationviewer.pri)
qtcAddDeployment()
```